# MySQL: sum values with join and group concatenation

Tags: mysql, sum, group-concatenation

I've got the following tables:

**users:**

```
mysql [test]> SHOW CREATE TABLE users\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: users
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**groups:**

```
mysql [test]> SHOW CREATE TABLE `groups`\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: groups
Create Table: CREATE TABLE groups (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

**products:**

```
mysql [test]> SHOW CREATE TABLE products\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: products
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I would like to know how many groups are active for a user:

```
mysql [test]> SELECT u.name, SUM(g.active) AS active FROM users u LEFT JOIN groups g ON (u.id = g.user_id) WHERE u.name IN ('user01', 'user02') GROUP BY u.name ORDER BY u.name;
+--------+--------+
| name   | active |
+--------+--------+
| user01 |      2 |
| user02 |      0 |
+--------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I also need a list of products per user but then `active` column show incorrect values due to `JOIN`:

```
mysql [test]> SELECT u.name, SUM(g.active) AS active, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.name ORDER BY p.name SEPARATOR ',') AS products FROM users u LEFT JOIN groups g ON (u.id = g.user_id) LEFT JOIN products p ON (u.product = p.product_id) WHERE u.name IN ('user01', 'user02') GROUP BY u.name ORDER BY u.name;
+--------+--------+-------------------------------+
| name   | active | products                      |
+--------+--------+-------------------------------+
| user01 |      6 | product01,product02,product03 |
| user02 |      0 | product11,product12,product13 |
+--------+--------+-------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So the expected results would be:

```
+--------+--------+-------------------------------+
| name   | active | products                      |
+--------+--------+-------------------------------+
| user01 |      2 | product01,product02,product03 |
| user02 |      0 | product11,product12,product13 |
+--------+--------+-------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Based on the following records:

```
mysql [test]> SELECT * FROM users;
+----+--------+---------+
| id | name   | product |
+----+--------+---------+
|  1 | user01 |       1 |
|  2 | user02 |       2 |
+----+--------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql [test]> SELECT * FROM groups;
+----+---------+---------+--------+
| id | user_id | name    | active |
+----+---------+---------+--------+
|  1 |       1 | group01 |      0 |
|  2 |       1 | group02 |      1 |
|  3 |       1 | group03 |      1 |
|  4 |       1 | group04 |      0 |
|  5 |       2 | group01 |      0 |
|  6 |       2 | group02 |      0 |
+----+---------+---------+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql [test]> SELECT * FROM products;
+----+-----------+------------+
| id | name      | product_id |
+----+-----------+------------+
|  1 | product01 |          1 |
|  2 | product02 |          1 |
|  3 | product03 |          1 |
|  4 | product11 |          2 |
|  5 | product12 |          2 |
|  6 | product13 |          2 |
+----+-----------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```